# Not able to fetch Google OAuth 2.0 access token

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-drive-realtime-api

I have tried to get an access token using the REST API by passing the parameters which are shown in screenshots below, but I face the error `Required parameter is missing: grant_type`. I have tried with cURL and the Advanced Rest API in a Chrome browser. I am sending these parameters using cURL and the Advanced REST API:

```
client_secret;xxx
refresh_token;
redirect_uri;https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Foauth2callback
scope;https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
client_id;xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
access_token;
```

cURL syntax:

```
D:\>curl -k --header Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded -i -X POST "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" -F 'code=4%2FdpbtMVUpzNFAfGHlxrNvfMlvHrPWk_m8y2I-thDdsLk.wvBSFgWEqW0Zcp7tdiljKKZFG-jOlgI' -F 'client_id=xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com' -F 'client_secret=xxx' -F 'redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Foauth2callback'  -F 'grant_type=authorization_code'
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're calling the token endpoint to exchange a `code` for an `access_token` as part of an Authorization Code grant. A few things:

1. don't use the `-F` flag as it will produce a `multipart-formdata` header but you need `www-form-urlencoded` as produced with `-d`
2. don't use the `-k` flag towards Google as that makes things insecure; Google presents a valid SSL certificate that you should check
3. put the `Content-Type` parameter in quotes

after adding some additional syntax optimization you should be able to use:

```
curl -v -i \
    -d "code=4%2FdpbtMVUpzNFAfGHlxrNvfMlvHrPWk_m8y2I-thDdsLk.wvBSFgWEqW0Zcp7tdiljKKZFG-jOlgI" \
    -d 'client_id=xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com' \
    -d 'client_secret=xxx' \
    -d 'redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Foauth2callback' \
    -d 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```