# Google login from android And Access auth token for server

Tags: android, laravel, google-signin, laravel-socialite

I am trying to **generate** server **auth** code in **android**

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
            .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.server_client_id), false)
            .build();
```

Then I have tried to get server auth code like this.

```
result.requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.server_client_id), false)
```

Suppose i got a auth token like 'bla bla bla';

Then using laravel socialite I am trying to get user on the server side

```
Socialize::driver('google')->userFromToken('bla bla bla')
```

It shows me error

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException with message 'Client error: GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?prettyPrint=false resulted in a 401 Unauthorized` response:
>   {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"authError","message":"Invalid Credentials","locationType":"header","loc (truncated...)

Comment: Use that auth code to get the access token, see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2, then use the access token for that endpoint

Comment: Thankyou for replying! I was looking on the web for that. can you show me how to get access_token from php or simply curl @BNK

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with php and curl, however, I think you can find more at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390718/not-able-to-fetch-google-oauth-2-0-access-token

Comment: got it any ways thanks

Comment: @AnandSiddharth Can you please help me even i am also in the same phase , i am trying to figure it out using laravel socialite plugin

Comment: @AnandSiddharth so do we have to use google client library for that

Comment: @AnandSiddharth You had missed to mention scope and that's why you were receiving the error. i.e. `Socialize::driver('google')->scopes(['profile','email'])->userFromToken('bla bla bla')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the code sent by google on android is not the access token to get access token you can do this on laravel controller.

Install this composer library https://github.com/pulkitjalan/google-apiclient

```
$client = new \PulkitJalan\Google\Client(['client_id' => 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 'client_secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET', 'redirect_uri' => 'YOUR_REDIRECT_URI', 'developer_key' => 'YOUR_KEY']);
$google = $client->getClient();
$google->authenticate($token);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken()["access_token"];

//and now here you go
$user = Socialize::driver('google')->userFromToken($access_token);
```

Comment: Where does the `$token` variable come from in line 3?

Comment: @Denitsa the token comes from the client as a post request, as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the Google_Client class that is provided from Google. you can find it [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth.)

Now, you've got two option:

1. You can send an **id_token** to the server, and validate it just as the link said and then just fetch the user info from the object received.
2. You can send the **backend_auth_code** to the server instead of the **id_token**, and then use the method ***fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code)***  of the Google_Client class. This gives you the access token, id token and other stuff. You can then use that **access_token** with Laravel Socialite

   ```
   $client = new Google_Client([
       'client_id' => config('services.google.client_id'),
       'client_secret' => config('services.google.client_secret')
   ]);

   $data = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);

   $user = Socialite::driver('google')->scopes(['profile','email'])->userFromToken($data['access_token']);
   ```